# OpenGL Shaders: How does the OpenGL Engine process two "parallel" arrays?

Tags: android, opengl-es, shader, vertex-shader

I am currently writing an Android OpenGL-ES 3.0 program in Java.

My app contains a large array that contains "position" data (aka, the vertices) of a complex object. I have created a Float buffer containing those vertices, and have correctly passed this as an attribute to the shaders. Everything draws correctly.

I'm trying to implement something new now. Within this vertex data set, the user selects a small subset (~1% of the original size). I would like this small subset of vertices to be colored green, leaving the rest of the object in its original color.

As I have it right now, I have a "parallel" array that contains information about the small subset. This array is the same size as the original, full data set. The array is initialized to 0. Then, the index in each element of each set of vertices in the small subset is changed to 1 in the "parallel" array. More simply:

Original data set:
(x0, y0, z0, x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2,...xn, yn, zn)

Subset:
(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2)

Parallel array:
(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,...0, 0, 0)

Now, my plan was to pass this parallel array as an attribute to the shaders, and then check if the point from the original data set had a corresponding "1" in the parallel data set. If it did, I changed the point's color to green. Here is my code:

```
        "uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix;      \n"     
      + "uniform mat4 u_MVMatrix;       \n"

      + "attribute vec4 a_Position;     \n" //This is the original position
      + "attribute vec4 a_Color;        \n"     
      + "attribute vec3 a_Normal;       \n"     
      + "attribute vec3 cran_Position;  \n" //This is the "parallel" array    

      + "varying vec3 v_Position;       \n"     
      + "varying vec4 v_Color;          \n"     
      + "varying vec3 v_Normal;         \n"     

      + "void main()                                                \n"     
      + "{                                                          \n"
      + "   v_Position = vec3(u_MVMatrix * a_Position);             \n"
      + "   v_Color = a_Color;                                      \n"
      + "   v_Normal = vec3(u_MVMatrix * vec4(a_Normal, 0.0));      \n"
      + "   gl_Position = u_MVPMatrix * a_Position;                 \n"

      //Check if the parallel array has a 1 at this point, if it does, color the point green.
      + "   if(cran_Position.x > 0.0){                              \n" 
      + "   v_Color.x = 0.0;                                        \n"
      + "   v_Color.y = 1.0;                                        \n"
      + "   v_Color.z = 0.0;}                                       \n"
      + "}                                                          \n";
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. Assume that I am correctly passing the full data and parallel array. I know there are other ways to get my desired effect of coloring the small subset green, but I would like to do this in the shader.

Is there anything glaringly incorrect about my logic?

Comment: Nothing glaringly obvious jumps out; the additional position array should work the same way as any other vertex attributes (e.g. your normals). Any reason you are uploading a vec3 float attribute to use only a single bit value? Seems expensive; a single GLubyte might be more efficient once you have it working.

Comment: Just for narrowing down the problem, you could use `cran_Position` as the color directly. That would show you if the attribute is passed to the shader correctly.

Comment: "*this does not work*" means it renders correctly but without green colors? "*Assume that I am correctly passing the full data and parallel array*" tbh I assume the opposite.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. LJ: Yes, it turns out that I am not passing the correct parallel array. Things were rendering but without green colors. I have fixed the parallel array and now things are working. @Isogen74, I'm not entirely sure how to use the GLubyte, since I am fairly new to OpenGL. How would I go about doing this instead of using a vec3?